# Use bootstrap component in angular component

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use a bootstrap collapsable panel into an angular component. 
From what i've seen the bootstrap approach is to use the id of the panel in order to collapse. This works as stand alone, however, when used into an angular component, the same id creates an undesired effect when toggle-ing between collapse and not collapse mode. ( always the first panel is collapsed/uncollapsed)

My next step was to create my custom collapse panel. This works and can be
seen here [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VKoMO7UrHeMbHaJG1AE4?p=preview) , but the collapse effect is not the same  ( the plunker link displays in parallel my panel and the bootstrap panel).

My question is how can i use the bootstrap panel into my component or how can i change the css to have the same bootstrap effect on collapse/un-collapse. ?

```
 <custom-filter-accordion button-text="Expand / Collapse Non-BootStrap"></custom-filter-accordion>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You should definitely use [Angular-ui's integration with bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse). For this specific purpose, they have a component called [`Collapse`](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse)

They already have lot of directives that you could use with angular and should speed up your development time

[Check this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nu1Zv1VzqE8YfYkkgEMM?p=preview)

Comment: I changed the code using your suggestions, but there is a slight glitch when the panel is collapsing . please check [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/VKoMO7UrHeMbHaJG1AE4?p=preview) . when the panel is collapsing at the end...there is a glitch that does not appear in the original bootstrap panel ...

Comment: Could you please post a plunker? That would help see the issue you are facing

Comment: here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VKoMO7UrHeMbHaJG1AE4?p=preview) . Please check the difference between custom-filter-accordion2 component and the third panel (bootstrap panel) when the collapse happens (especially at the end of the collapse transition)

Comment: Just move the uib-collapse directive one dom level higher. check this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SbvKZe1BldqOntrbXi0l?p=preview) Its much smooth here.

Comment: It is better now. I appreciate